# Getting clicked ActionLink id and passing it as function argument

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc, actionlink

Been struggling with this for over a day, how can I pass an actionlink id to a jquery ajax call to enable a partial page update.

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink(@item.strCountry, "Index", "Weather", new { id = Regex.Replace(@item.strCountry, " ", "-") }, new { @class = "getCities" })</li>
```

jQuery

```
<script>
 $(function () {
     $(".getCities").click(function () {
         $.ajax({
             //url: this.href,
             url: '@Url.Action("pvDisplayListOfWeatherCities", "Weather")',
             type: 'GET',
             data: { id: $('#id').val() },
             dataType: 'Json',
             success: function (result) {
                 alert(result.test);
             },
             error: function () {
                 alert("error");
             }
         });
         return false;
     });
 });
</script>
```

Thanks

George

Comment: as an added note : the `dataType` attribute is case sensitive. it should be `"json"` instead of `"Json"`.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood the question correctly then you change:

`data: { id: $('#id').val() },`

to

`data: { id: $(this).attr('id') },`

**Edit** - all you need is `data: { id: $(this).text() },`

Comment: Hi boz, I have tried that, value is still null, the html produced is <li><a class="getCities" href="/Weather/Index/Afghanistan">Afghanistan</a></li> even if I could just get the 'value' from between the <a href>value</a> is all i need

Comment: @boz Using `text()` will not work the same, because value that is set as text can have space inside and it's replaced by `Regex.Replace` for `id` of link, so I assume that controller expects only ids with spaces replaced.

Comment: @KonradGadzina - That all makes sense but I was simply answering the OP's comment about the value he wanted to get.

Comment: Hi Sorry should have explained better, the Regex.Replace(@item.strCountry is there in case the page does a full page refresh and it ensures the url has - between each word, in the controller all characters except az -09 are removed

Answer (score 1):

Add the parameter(s) as HTML attribute(s)

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink(@item.strCountry, "Index", "Weather", 
    new { id = Regex.Replace(@item.strCountry, " ", "-") }, 
    new { @class = "getCities", data_param1 = Regex.Replace(@item.strCountry, " ", "-") })</li>
```

this will render:

```
<li><a class="getCities" href="/Weather/Index/val" data-param1="val">country</a></li>
```

and then use the jQuery `.attr()` method:

```
<script>
 $(function () {
     $(".getCities").click(function () {
         $.ajax({
             //url: this.href,
             url: '@Url.Action("pvDisplayListOfWeatherCities", "Weather")',
             type: 'GET',
             data: { id: $(this).attr("data-param1") }, // <-- param1 etc.
             dataType: 'json',
             success: function (result) {
                 alert(result.test);
             },
             error: function () {
                 alert("error");
             }
         });
         return false;
     });
 });
</script>
```

Comment: Is it possible to award both you the answer as both options work

Comment: @CareerChange You can vote up any helpfull answer, but only one can be marked as approved.

Comment: I have marked everyones answer up one as all work, thanks everyone for their help

Answer (score 1):

You're not setting `id` attribute for this link, you're just setting id that is used as a parameter to build link itself. You should simply add `id` attribute for this tag

```
<li>@Html.ActionLink(@item.strCountry, "Index", "Weather", 
    new { id = Regex.Replace(@item.strCountry, " ", "-") }, 
    new { @class = "getCities", @id = Regex.Replace(@item.strCountry, " ", "-")})</li>
```

if you want it to be the same as `id` of parameter in your link. And then update this

```
data: { id: $('#id').val() },
```

to this

```
data: { id: $(this).attr('id') },
```

to get the actual `id` attribute of this HTML tag.